# How to open book in pdf/txt in Chrome so I can use google translate extension while reading it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-translate, browser-addons

so I have this book in pdf format. I would like to read it while using the Google translator extension that I have installed in my Chrome browser. These are the things that I have tried so far:

- Drag pdf file to Chrome. Chrome opens the file but the extension
  doesn't work.
- Convert the pdf file to txt. Drag the txt file to Chrome. Again, text
  is shown but extension is not working.
- Built an html file from the txt with an online txt-html converter.
  The html is openned by Chrome and the content is perfectly readable
  but the extension doesn't work neither.

I don't understand why. The extension works perfectly in any other webpage on the internet. I just select a word or sentence and the translation option appears instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally used https://pages.github.com/ to have the .txt version online and works smoothly.